# php header function redirects to only local pages

Tags: php, redirect, header

i use php's header() to redirect users to external links. but it redirects to only internal pages, following is the example.

```
 header('location: google.com');
```

the above code is only redirecting to:

```
 www.mydomain.com/google.com
```

the location "google.com" is received from get variable. when i try to use "http://google.com" in the get varialbe it gives 403 error page.

i want the header function to redirect to the external link not to my domain name.

Comment: 403 error page from where? from your server?

Comment: Try this  `header('location:http://www.google.com');`

Comment: @KrishR he already did that.

Comment: @itachi yes it gives 403 error from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
header("Location: http://www.google.com/"); /* Redirect browser */
```

Comment: as i said, the link is from a get variable, so if i use that url, it send me to the 403 page.

Comment: Please tell me how it is solved. what is the root cause.

Comment: as i can't send the "http://" with the url through get variable(in the url) i concated the "http://"  string in here...header('location: http://'.$_GET['link']); so it will be redirected to external url.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<?php
    header('Location: http://google.com/'); 
?>
```

Note: The header function goes within the  section of the PHP document and has to be placed before any HTML tags.

You can also use the [Meta Tag "Refresh"](http://webmaster.iu.edu/tools-and-guides/maintenance/redirect-meta-refresh.phtml) to redirect users. With this HTML tag you can determine how long the user will be on the page before it redirects.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to external link use http followed by the site name:

```
<?php 
header('Location:http://google.com');//redirects to google.com
?>
```